# Match values of csv

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, web-scraping

I request advice on a Pythonic matter I am confused about. I have a csv file which holds a ***field value*** I need to search by on a website. Next, I want to tell Python if you find any matching values corresponding to the ***field value*** in the csv file, save the records into a new csv file. Please provide your assistance on how and what modules I can use to accomplish this task. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

```
import requests
import bs4
import csv

r = requests.get('https://etrakit.friscotexas.gov/Search/permit.aspx')

with open ('C:/Users/Desktop/Programming/Addresses.csv') as f:
    for row in csv.reader(f):
        print row[1]
```

Comment: With a pseudo like that you probably can show us some python attempt

Comment: I did try beautifulsoup and requests module but could not get anything going. I just need the right module to get going.

Comment: If all you want is matching text, just use string search.  If you want something more complicated, you need to explain the problem better.

Comment: for crawling in python, you can use [scrapy](https://scrapy.org)

Comment: The website is pretty, straightforward. Search by the addresses field in the csv field and whatever data Python can find, save into a new csv file.

Comment: If your task is to scrape site data, [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) is the best tool for the job.